# Does Catalyst Control Center Manual Fan Control get disabled when GPU dangerously overheats?

Tags: fan, amd-radeon, cooling, amd-catalyst

I'd like to enable AMD Overdrive and Manual Fan Control in Catalyst Control Center and reduce fan speed to minimum (20%) but I'm afraid what happens if I start using the card heavily and forget to disable Manual Fan Control.

Will it disable by itself when temperature reaches some dangerously high value or will the fan will stay obediently at low speed and GPU will crash or gets damaged due to overheating?

Comment: you might try setting the fan to 20% and then putting stress on the gpu while you're sitting there closely monitoring it to see what happens. If it gets too hot and the fan still hasn't come on, then quit the test and you have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to reduce it's speed to 20%? If it's running higher there's a very good reason... 
Your card is HOT!

Forcibly reducing its speed will cause the temperature to rise and i'm fairly confident because you've specified the speed it will happily overheat and crash. Leave it on auto if you want it to be the quietest, if it's still too loud then look at a 3rd party cooling solution. Some of these coolers will work more efficently, some almost cooling enough passively for low load/idle times... Hence very low fan speeds (and less noise).

Comment: Fan is running at 40% and the GPU is at 39C

If I switch to manual control and lower it to 20% then GPU is at 39C

When I set it to 100% which sounds like fighter jet then GPU is at 39C periodically dropping to 38C for a moment.

Do you know the answer to my question?

Comment: Personally... I'd unplug the header (no fan) then sit and watch it to see how warm it gets! Make sure you replace the side of your case to emulate 'standard' operation. If it hardly moves it may be worth using it for 3-4+ hours and then checking.

Comment: I don't directly know the answer to your question, that would be one to throw at AMD/Catalyst Developers if it's not mentioned in any manuals :)